# Trying to delete a project version yields "You cannot delete this version because it is used by a label"

Tags: google-apps-script

Has anyone ever seen such a thing? How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: I can't help, but had the same issue and raised it on the clasp CLI tool https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/224

Answer (score 0):

Is your app deployed in any manner (i.e. using the options in the `Publish` menu)?

If so, make sure that no deployments are associated with the version you're attempting to delete.

Comment: it's deployed, but isn't associated with any version but the last (185). I tried searching this issue on the web and found no mention of such a case. I tried to search for versions and labels, but got nothing but people talking about using GAS  to update Gmail labels on their emails ...

Comment: I also removed the Web App deployment and it still hasn't helped and I got the same message.